# Cannot add archetype on IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ to work with Flink project and then I would like to use archetype (flink-quickstart-java).

However, after I clicked Add archetype, and entered all parameter, there is no new archetype for me to select for creating my own project.

Is there anything needed to be configure?

[image]

Comment: Looks like this issue: (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-271557)[IDEA-271557] Cannot add new Maven archetype in New Project wizard. It will be fixed in 2021.3 version update.

Comment: The youtrack link seems to be dead.

Comment: I tried the 2021.3 EAP, the problem persists, nothing changed.

Comment: As of 2021.3 EAP Build #IC-213.5449.25, the problem still persists.

Comment: I used a workaround though - Downloaded an older version - 2021.1.3, setup the archetype & the project, opened in latest 2021.2.

Comment: Not surprisingly, bug replicable on 2021.2.4

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I restarted intellij after creating the archetype, and it appeared as expected.

Answer (score -1):

1. Go to File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Maven > Repositories.
2. Select every URL
3. Update

[image: IntelliJ Settings]

Answer (score -5):

I was able to add the archetype using the Add Archetype button:
[image]
This is the configuration that I used:
[image]